# Use hosts file on PC to access a server rather than internet

Tags: google-chrome, dns, host

I have a server that I am remotely connected to.

Its IP is 192.168.1.1

It is mapped in my local hosts file to :

```
192.168.1.1 www.facebook.com
```

When I type in www.facebook.com , it take me to the Facebook login page BUT I want to goto my server.

How can I force my Chrome browser to goto my server rather than global DNS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome caches DNS queries, which might be an issue here.
Go to [chrome://net-internals/#dns](http://chrome://net-internals/#dns) clear the DNS cache and see if that helps.